# UICollectionViewLayout.prepare() - any way to get the cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

In the `prepare()` method of UICollectionViewLayout, I'd like to ask the cell what its preferred height is for a given width. However, it isn't clear how I can get the cell and its data inside the prepare function. `cellForItem(at:)` returns nil. I'm considering simply defining a protocol that the collection view's controller can conform to, but I want to see if a cleaner implementation is possible.

Comment: `cellForItem(at:)` returns a visible cell at the index path.  If the cell is not visible, this will return nil.  The `prepare()` method calculates layout attributes for all index paths, visible or not, therefore this is not the method to use.